# хранение параметров между подключениями клиента через HTTP(s) к серверу на GoLang

Tags: api, golang, http

толкните в нужном направлении )
есть приложение на Android есть сервер на GoLang. обмен предполагается делать через API.
 пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию через SRP. но процесс авторизации выполняется в 3 шага. если в приложении понятно где хранить промежуточные результаты, то на стороне сервера - не понимаю... 
думал что session спасет, но, насколько я понял, сервер параметры сессии отправляет на клиента и потом проверяет, что от этого же клиента получено обратно. передавать рассчитанные ключи.. так себе удовольствие. 
какими механизмами хранить параметры между подключениями клиента?

Comment: Вы должны понимать, что отвечающие не знают ни специфику вашего проекта, не данные, которые вам нужно хранить. Лучше чем хранить все в бд судя по вашему тексту вопроса вам не посоветуют. Постарайтесь объяснить все в общих терминах, пока ваш вопрос не заминусовали

Comment: есть алгоритм авторизации SRP,  реализованный, например (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/1Password/srp?utm_source=godoc) он подразумевает что клиент и сервер должны 3 раза обменяться информацией. последовательно. т.е. каждый следующий шаг основан на всех предыдущих. вот и возник вопрос как хранить информацию между этими шагами на сервере, для которого каждое подключение как новое. <br>хранить в базе. логично. и пока это единственное  что я могу придумать.. но не уверен что это оптимальное решение. возможно в go есть более продвинутые механизмы.

Comment: В srp не углублялся, но сервер может возвращать еще данные о предыдущих шагах, и тогда ему ничего не придется хранить. В любом случае задача кажется тривиальной, попробуйте погуглить "SRP server golang examples"

Comment: гуглил конечно, но все примеры идут  в один слой. как будто клиент и сервер в одной функции написаны. последовательно показываются какие функции библиотеки надо вызывать. а именно этот момент, как то упущен. и/или я не в одном примере этого не заметил (

Comment: Ваш сервер на go хранит состояние, т.е. это же не php, чтобы умирать после каждого request-а, соответственно, вы вообще можете map-у создать и хранить по киленту предыдущие шаги. Однако, какое-то хранилище будет более канонично смотреться, т.к. буковка D в ACID вам даст отказоустойчивость, т.е. в ситуации, если ваш процесс убьет k8s, вы заного вычитаете все из хранилища и избавите клиент от ненужных телодвижений.

Comment: условный exe в памяти-то храниться, но новое обращение к условному http.HandleFunc создает же новую "ветку-процесс". т.е. чтобы условная func2 знала о каких-то результатах func1. нужно создать какую то внешнюю для обоих функций переменную. вы предлагаете инициализировать в main() структуру map и обоими функциями ее использовать? что ж - вариант ) я пока нашел в реализации SRP Marshal/Unmarshal и храню эти данный в базе